# If page or sub page not working as expected

Tags: pages, sidebar, child-pages

I would like to display a specific dynamic sidebar the the "about" page and its children. [From the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/), I have tried the following:

```
<?php 
  // Begin main loop
  if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ):
  the_post();

  // If about page and about child pages
  if ( is_page('about') && $post->post_parent > 0 ) {
    dynamic_sidebar('about');
  }

  else {
    dynamic_sidebar('general');
  }

  // End loop
  endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

This doesn't work. What am I missing?

I've also tried the following. This works for grandparents and parents, but not children.

```
<?php

  if (is_page (17) || (17 == $post->post_parent ) ) {
    dynamic_sidebar('about');
  }

  else {
    dynamic_sidebar('general');
  }

?>
```

Here's a post object dump of a child page using `<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r( $post, true ); ?>`:

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 382
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2018-08-15 17:02:56
    [post_date_gmt] => 2018-08-15 16:02:56
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => Art
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => art
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2018-10-22 12:39:27
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2018-10-22 11:39:27
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 378
    [guid] => http://domain.local/?page_id=382
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => page
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the widget area be outside of the loop?

Comment: @Pim Doesn't seem to make a difference. I've tried without `&& $post->post_parent > 0 )` and it works perfectly.

Comment: This is probably a due to a misunderstanding in how global variables work in PHP versus normal ones. I'd also advise against bundling up stuff like `endwhile; endif;` with the same indenting, or putting multiple things on the same line, it's a great way to make mistakes and it makes code harder to read

Comment: My `endwhile; endif;` aren't on the same line within my template. I just included a simpler version for my question.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to get the about page's ID and use that in your comparison:

```
if ( is_page( 'about' ) || $about_page_id == $post->post_parent ) {
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `if ( is_page(17) && $post->post_parent > 0 ) {`

Comment: I think you want to OR that with `||` and use the condition above. Your current conditional says "If this is the About page AND this page's parent is not zero." I think what you want is "is this the About page OR is it a child of the About page?"

Comment: I just saw your edit about grandparents and parents. Can you dump one of the child posts using `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $post, true );` and add it to your question?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here?

Comment: While you're in the loop, you can dump the current `$post` onto the screen using the code snippet above. We can then inspect the values such as `post_parent` to see if they line up with what you're expecting.

Comment: Sorry for the radio silence @phatskat. I've updated the question with that dump.